# Android 6.0 and Amazon S3 SDK open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, amazon-s3, permission-denied, android-6.0-marshmallow

Recently I've discovered that my app doesn't allow me to pick images and upload it to Amazon S3 on Android 6.0 Marshmallow due to the new runtime permission model. So, I've added this code in my activity ('add image' button listener):

```java
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
           != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.permlab_media_request)
                .setMessage(R.string.permdesc_media_request)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, 0);
    }
} else {
    openPicker();
}
```

and this activity implements `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`:

```java
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode != 0) {
        return;
    }
    if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        openPicker();
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly - the permission dialog is being shown correctly and if the user allows app to access external storage the image picker is opened and populated with available images on SD card.
However when I try to upload selected image to Amazon S3 using this code:

```
final TransferObserver transferObserver = mTransferUtil.upload(AmazonUtility.Constants.BUCKET_NAME, fileKey, file);
```

it fails with such a message in log:

```
E/UploadTask: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /storage/0E17-2F07/Pictures/device-2015-12-03-184153.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

These permissions are also declared in the manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any ideas why Amazon SDK is restricted to access external SD card?
On devices with lower APIs (<23) all this code works fine and files get uploaded successfully. Also I'd like to notice that a run this app on emulator with Android 6.0.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the problem was with the emulator. I've found a real Android 6 device and launched app on it - and the code posted above worked fine without any error. I really can't understand why API 23 emulator with studio managed 500Mb SD card behaves like that. Hope guys from Google will improve their emulator